# PCF redis credentials with stackexchange redis

Tags: c#, .net, stackexchange.redis, pcfdev

I am trying to configure redis with `PCF` redis credentials. While doing operations RedisServer exception keep on coming.

Can anyone explain how `PCF` and redis will work?

Code

```
private static Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer> lazyConnection = new Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer>(() =>
{
    return ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("ip:port,password=taswar-foobared,abortConect = false, ssl= true or false");
});

public static ConnectionMultiplexer Connection
{
    get
    {
        return lazyConnection.Value;
    }
}
```

`PCF` Enviroment variables showing host like 10.10.10.10, port and password